Could I use GCN get nodes structual embedding without training?
Now, I want to get nodes' structual embedding, use DeepWalk or Node2Vec couldn't get same vector even they have same structure. then I use GCN which could get same vector without training. So I want use it but I haven't fount paper use it yet. Could I use it to get node vector?

Welcome to Data Science SE @yiyi:) !! Could you provide more detail about your use case? For instance, are you constrained by computational resources, or are you looking for a method that avoids parameter learning altogether? Please edit your question with your response, since many users don't check the comments section.
